# Sketch App - Text on path placement

Tags: path, sketch-app

I'm trying to create a text on the outside of a path. In a different question I found how to do this; by vertically flipping the shape and this works.

However, when I move the text to position it straight, it 'bugs' out. When I move it somewhere else, it's okay again. What am I doing wrong and how should I place the text so it's straight but curved on top of my shape?

[image: bug]
[image: moved around, suddenly fixes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's some kind of rendering bug as this happens with any text on path when I move, zoom out etc.

Upon exporting everything is fine.